# How to store/apply the access token when connecting to Soundcloud via its JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

I've got a Soundcloud-application and am trying to make an authenticated call to it via the Javascript-API. However I can't reuse the authorized session because the JS-API can't remember the access token.

I've read about a planned change regarding this sessions-persistence here [How to get access_token via Javascript SDK on SoundCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196411/how-to-get-access-token-via-javascript-sdk-on-soundcloud) but afaik it never was introduced.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted my answer for anybody still trying to figure this one out over here

[How to have users 'reconnect' with soundcloud on each page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116532/how-to-have-users-reconnect-with-soundcloud-on-each-page-reload/18924709#18924709)

Comment: SC.accessToken() is undefined, it gives you nothing

Comment: @JitenderYadav did you initialize SC first?

Comment: yup, I had initialized SC. I have found the accessToken now, it is passed as parameter in the SC.connect() method.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i got it right,
you can request a non-expiring token.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#token